# Usar CONCAT para ajustar a quantidade de números php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Eu preciso completar a quantidade de números para exibição na tela,o que seria isso. a **quantidade** que seria exemplo: 20 preciso inteirar 15 caracteres com 0,

Exemplo: **000000000000020**.

Um amigo meu me mostrou no Excel um forma que ele usa o **CONCAT** e depois pega somente os últimos 15 números,com isso o id pode ser 1,100,100 etc ... que ele vai ser sempre 15 números que seria os zeros mais a quantidade.

Eu olhei aqui no site e também na internet mais não consegui fazer o que preciso,alguém teria alguma dica.

Esse resultado eu trago do MySQL,se for mais fácil no MySQL posso usar também.

Segue um exemplo da consulta que tentei fazer:

```
SELECT 
 MAX(cup_id)             AS CUPOM,
 MAX(DATE_FORMAT(c.cup_data_hora, '%d/%m/%Y'))    AS DATA,
 MAX(c.cup_data_hora)    AS HORA,
 MAX(l.loja_num)         AS LOJA_NUM,
 MAX(l.loja_desc)        AS LOJA_NOME,
 MAX(l.loja_end)         AS END_LOJA,
 MAX(u.usu_cod)          AS USU_ID,
 MAX(u.usu_nome)         AS USU_NOME,
 MAX(v.vas_cod_emporium) AS COD_EMPORIUM,
 MAX( v.vas_desc)        AS VASILHAME,
 MAX(c.cup_quantidade)   AS QUANTIDADE,
 CONCAT(c.cup_quantidade,'000000000000') AS QUANTIDADE_15
FROM cupom  AS c
 LEFT JOIN loja      AS l ON c.cup_loja      = l.loja_num
 LEFT JOIN vasilhame AS v ON c.cup_vasilhame = v.vas_id
 LEFT JOIN usuarios  AS u ON c.cup_usu_id    = u.usu_cod
   WHERE cup_loja =4**
```

Comment: vc quer definir um número de com digitos fixo, por exemplo 5, caso o número seja 20 ele coloque 3 zeros a esquerda?

Comment: Já tentou usar o campo na tabela com ZEROFILL ?

Comment: @rray isso mesmo

Comment: @Zoom , consegui com a ajuda do nosso colega rray ,mais depois vou ver essa sua parte também,obrigado pelo retorno.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a função [`lpad()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) do MySQL para adicionar um 'prefixo' a esquerda da string, o primeiro argumento pode ser o campo que será modificado, o segundo é o comprimento(4 caracteres) e o último é o caracter que será adicionado.

```
SELECT lpad('1',4,0)
SELECT lpad('10',4,0)
SELECT lpad('100',4,0)
SELECT lpad('1000',4,0)
```

As saidas são:

```
0001 
0010
0100
1000
```

**[Exemplo - sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8cc07b/3)**

Comment: Tudo certo,obrigado mais uma vez.