# Acrescentar dígitos a campo auto increment do banco de dados

Tags: mysql

Preciso acrescentar no campo Id banco de dados MySQL, que é *auto increment*, o valor **0** até completar 4 dígitos - irá servir como número de nota fiscal.

No form não manipulo esse item, tem que ser diretamente no banco de dados ou acrescentar os dígitos via código mas sem inserir esse campo no form, pois não precisa ser manipulável.

Comment: Mas isso em qual momento? Num select? Queres fazer um update? Precisa ser mais específico.

Comment: Vai inserir "0" à esquerda ou à direita? Não surtirá efeitos à esquerda em campos numéricos, e se for à direita, e já tiverem registros, poderá duplicar. Em todo caso, campo ID auto incrementado não se mexe (provável que seja chave PK). Por que não cria um campo para isso?

Comment: Acredito que [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/126604/91) resolva.

Comment: @rray, é isso que preciso. Obrigado