# Colocar 00 a esquerda em outra variável

Tags: javascript, mysql

Tenho um formulário em HTML que recebe o número de acordo com a ID cadastrada no SQL e salva em outra variável, porém a ID é sequencial e sem zero a esquerda, exemplo:

```
ID 1
ID 2
ID 3
```

Precisava pegar esse ID e colocar na variável Número da seguinte forma:

```
001
002
003
```

Teria que ser feito via JS ou pode ser feito direto via MySQL?

Comment: Direto pelo mysql [faça dessa forma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/126604/91)

Comment: @rray O problema do método da sua resposta é que ele quer colocar dois zeros a esquerda independente do tamanho do ID, o que vc sugeriu completa com zeros até obter um quantidade de dígitos específica

Comment: @bfavaretto nem tinha notado que tinha pra Js :/ devia ter respondido lá, se bem que varia um pouco, já que lá parece limitar a string, mas no geral deve ser a mesma coisa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em mysql o @rray já sugeriu

> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/126604/3635

Seria algo como no seu caso:

```
SELECT lpad('1', 3, 0)
```

Em JavaScript tem este exemplo https://stackoverflow.com/a/20460414/1518921 basta fazer o ajuste para 3 zeros:

```js
var input = '1';
var lpadresult = ('000' + input).slice(-3);

console.log(lpadresult);
```

4 dígitos:

```js
var input = '1';
var lpadresult = ('0000' + input).slice(-4);

console.log(lpadresult);
```

Ou então uma função adaptada:

```js
function strpad(input, size, right, prefix) {
    //o array gera os zeros para usar na frente ou depois
    var ps = Array(size).join(prefix ? prefix : "0");
    
    //Inverte para o sufixo
    if (right) {
        return (input + ps).slice(0, size);
    } else {
        return (ps + input).slice(-size);
    }
}

//3 prefixos
console.log(strpad('1', 3));
console.log(strpad('22', 3));
console.log(strpad('333', 3));
console.log(strpad('4444', 3));

console.log("-----------");

//4 prefixos
console.log(strpad('1', 4));
console.log(strpad('22', 4));
console.log(strpad('333', 4));
console.log(strpad('4444', 4));

console.log("-----------");

//3 sufixos
console.log(strpad('1', 3, true));
console.log(strpad('22', 3, true));
console.log(strpad('333', 3, true));
console.log(strpad('4444', 3, true));

console.log("-----------");

//4 sufixos
console.log(strpad('1', 4, true));
console.log(strpad('22', 4, true));
console.log(strpad('333', 4, true));
console.log(strpad('4444', 4, true));

console.log("-----------");

//Prefixo customizado
console.log(strpad('1', 4, false, 'B'));
console.log(strpad('22', 6, false, 'C'));
console.log(strpad('333', 8, false, 'Y'));
console.log(strpad('4444', 9, false, 'Z'));
```