# Completar número com zeros à esquerda com PHP

Tags: php, html

Tenho um campo com limite de 4 caracteres onde irá entrar um valor, gostaria que o espaço restante se completasse com zeros da esquerda pra direita, por exemplo, se o usuário insere o número 4. Teria que sair 0004, se inserisse 100, teria que sair 0100, se fosse inserido 1000, sairia 1000 e assim por diante.

Como consigo fazer isso com PHP?

Comment: Você quer que esses zeros já apareçam no momento que o usuário digita um valor? Se sim, precisará fazer com JavaScript.

Comment: Não é necessário, basta que o output saia dessa forma

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Utilize a função [str_pad](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) em conjunto com a flag `STR_PAD_LEFT`.

```
echo str_pad('5' , 4 , '0' , STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Saída:

> 0005

Ou com 100:

```
echo str_pad('100' , 4 , '0' , STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Saída:

> 0100

Comment: Caso eu tenha uma variavel:
$number = 30;
Basta fazer dessa forma?
echo str_pad( $number , 4 , '0' , STR_PAD_LEFT);
?

Comment: @FelipeRodrigues exatamente isso, basta adicionar ao primeiro parâmetro.

Answer (score 7):

Use função [`str_pad()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) para adicionar os zeros a esquerda e passe o quarto argumento como `STR_PAD_LEFT`.

```
echo str_pad(1, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo str_pad(10, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo str_pad(100, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo str_pad(1000, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Saída:

```
0001
0010
0100
1000
```

**Relacionada:**

[Usar CONCAT para ajustar a quantidade de números php mysql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126603/91)

Answer (score 0):

Faça assim:

```
$num = 13;
echo sprintf("%04s",$num);
```

A saída será: 0013.

Caso deseje 5 zeros, altere o "04" para "05". Assim por diante, a quantidade de zeros à esquerda, que desejar.

Comment: Não entendo por quê, deram downvote nisso.

Comment: Boa Jetro. ajudou muito