# Loop de sequência numérica em PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Bom dia

Tenho o resultado no MYSQL

```
01
03
04
06
11
```

Preciso de uma solução que preencha com 2 zeros onde perde a sequência numérica até o número 12.

Exemplo:

```
01
00
03
04
00
06
00
00
00
00
11
00
```

Comment: Relacionada: [Completar número com zeros à esquerda automaticamente em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/249883/91)

Comment: Entendi o que quer... vou acertar

Comment: Como está a ler os valores do mysql ? Estão a ser lidos como inteiros ou como texto prefixado de 0 ?

Comment: Os valores estão configurados como Varchar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma possibilidade para resolver isso é:

```
<?php 
$array_do_banco = array('01', '03', '04', '06', '11');
$array_saida = array();

for($i=1; $i<13; $i++){
    if(in_array($i, $array_do_banco)){
        $matches = array_keys($array_do_banco, $i);
        $array_saida[$i-1] = $array_do_banco[$matches[0]];
    }else{
        $array_saida[$i-1] = '00';
    }
}

var_dump($array_saida);
?>
```

A saída é:

> array(12) { [0]=> string(2) "01" [1]=> string(2) "00" [2]=> string(2) "03" [3]=> string(2) "04" [4]=> string(2) "00" [5]=> string(2) "06" [6]=> string(2) "00" [7]=> string(2) "00" [8]=> string(2) "00" [9]=> string(2) "00" [10]=> string(2) "11" [11]=> string(2) "00" }

Comment: Sugestão, troque `[$i-1]` por `[]`, vai funcionar da mesma forma.

Answer (score 5):

Acho uma solução seria:

```
$mysql = ['01', '03', '04', '06', '11'];
$final = array_fill(0, max(12, max($mysql)), '00');

foreach($mysql as $n){
    $final[(int)$n-1] = $n;
}

var_dump($final);
```

Resultado:

```
array(12) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "01"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "00"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "03"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "04"
  [4]=>
  string(2) "00"
  [5]=>
  string(2) "06"
  [6]=>
  string(2) "00"
  [7]=>
  string(2) "00"
  [8]=>
  string(2) "00"
  [9]=>
  string(2) "00"
  [10]=>
  string(2) "11"
  [11]=>
  string(2) "00"
}
```

---

A ideia é bem simples, criamos com 12 valores, com tudo `00`, usando o `array_fill`. Depois, apenas substituímos os valores baseados no `$mysql`.

*Como o `$mysql` possui valores em `string` não podemos usa-lo diretamente na array, para isso então passamos para int usando o `(int)$n`. Dessa forma o valor `03` ficaria como $final[3] = '03'.*

O `max(12, max($mysql))` foi adicionado para que gere 12 valores, como solicitado em sua pergunta Entretanto, algum valor do `$mysql` extrapolar o 12 será utilizado tal número. Nessa situação, se for `$mysql = ['01', '111'];` ele ainda funcionará.

---

Embora pessoalmente não fosse usar, existe uma outra forma, ainda sem utilizar `if`, `foreach` ou `while` explicitamente:

```
$resultado_do_mysql = ['01', '03', '04', '06', '11'];

$final = array_replace(array_fill(1, 12, '00'), array_combine(array_map('intval', $mysql), $mysql));

var_dump($final);
```

O que fazemos neste caso é criar uma outra array, para isso fazemos o valor ir de *string* para *int* (usando o `array_map('intval', $mysql)`). Então, usamos tal valor em int como index do array, ainda mantendo o valor original usando `array_combine(array_map('intval', $mysql), $mysql)`. Por fim, substituímos o valor do `$final` com o valor de tal array, usando o `array_replace`. *Acredito que isto seja mais confuso do que o primeiro método.*

Comment: Sugestão breve: Eu pegaria o ultimo numero do array (ou o maior) e somaria a 1, então ao invés de `,12` seria o ultimo numero encontrado, assim acaso o mysql retorne mais dados o código ainda iria funcionar.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, adicionei um `max()` para que o `12` seja o minimo ou então o último valor do *mysql*, que deve ser o maior. O `12` é porque o OP determinou sendo 12 mesmo.

Comment: Minha sugestão seria usar `max([01, 100])`, retornaria `100`, sendo assim o que importa mais é o maior valor dentro e não o ultimo item do array.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, É faz sentido, se estiver desordenado iria funcionar. Acho que agora está do jeito que falou. :D

Comment: Desculpe se pareço chato, então este concat que você usou `[12] + $mysql` não funciona da forma que você acredita (ao menos me pareceu que a intenção esperada é outra), por exemplo `var_dump([12] + ['01', '03', '04', '06', '11'])` irá **trocar** o valor do index = ficar com o valor 12, o correto provavelmente seria usar `array_merge` que vai mesclar as arrays.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, nem me lembrava disso, faz tempo que não uso PHP. :P Acho que neste caso seria mais fácil fazer `max(12, max($mysql))`, acho que fica mais fácil de entender. Se tiver outro erro pode falar. ;)

Comment: Tem só mais um erro, o teu indice (index) inicia no `1`: `array(12) {
  [1]=>` - isto por causa do teu `foreach`, seria melhor trocar o foreach inteiro por simplesmente isto: `$mysql = ['01', '03', '04', '06', '11']; $final = array_fill(1, max(12, max($mysql)), '00'); $final = array_values($final);`, além de "corrigir" o indice ele desta forma vai reduzir o código :)

Comment: Não trocou o foreach por array_values por algum motivo? ps: ao meu ver a sua resposta é a melhor :) As dicas que lhe dei foram só para melhorar o que já era bom, fico no aguardo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, não sei isso era necessário, porque o `array_values` iria percorrer tudo de novo. Acho que simplesmente começar de `0` e fazer `$n-1` atinge o mesmo objetivo.

Comment: entendi sua lógica, eu pensei que era outra coisa, talvez eu formule um exemplo com o que imaginei e te mande, abraço +1

Answer (score 1):

Amigo,

Da para fazer algo nessa linha do código abaixo, o qual lanço comentado:

```
<?php
$numeros = array("01", "03", "04", "06", "11"); // que vieram do banco

// criamos uma função para adicionar o zero na frente do número
function zeroes($n) {
  return ((int) $n) < 10 ? "0{$n}" : "{$n}";
}

// aqui fazemos o for/loop para agregar as 12 entradas no array $resultado
$resultado = array();
for($i=1; $i<=12; $i++) {
  // usamos o in_array para saber se o teu numero existe no array original
  if(in_array($numeros, zeroes($i))) {
    // se tiver, adicionamos ele na sequencia
    $resultado[] = zeroes($i);
  } else {
    // caso não adicionamos o valor "00"
    $resultado[] = "00";
  }
}

print_r($resultado);
```

O conceito básico aqui é em um loop de 1 a 12, verificar se o numero atual do giro do loop está entre os numeros que vieram do seu banco, caso não esteja, adiciona 00 na sequencia, caso esteja permanece o numero original... mais ou menos por ai.

Answer (score 0):

Um exemplo mais simplificado de se fazer seria pegando apenas o maior valor e com um loop checando o que existe, a lógica seria usar o array vindo do banco apenas para saber quantos loops serão necessários pegando o valor máximo obtido no array com `max()`, então se for maior que 12, vai ter mais de 12 ciclos, se for menor vai ter exatamente 12 ciclos, exemplo:

```
<?php
$mysql = array( '01', '03', '04', '06', '11' );

//O max dentro verifica qual o maior numero, o outro verifica se é maior ou não que 12
$max = max(12, max($mysql));

//Será o resultado final
$final = array();

//Faz um loop baseado no valor máximo
for ($i = 1; $i <= $max; $i++) {

    //Gera o valor atual
    $current = str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

    //Checa se o valor atual existe no array que veio do banco
    if (in_array($current, $mysql)) {
        $final[] = $current;
    } else { //Se não existir preenche com 2 ZEROs
        $final[] = '00';
    }
}

print_r($final);
```

O loop começa no `1` pois assim evita que precisemos fazer algo como `$i-1` dentro do `for`, exemplo no [ideone](https://ideone.com/Sa1lgQ)