# Acrescentar um numero na frente de todos os registros

Tags: mysql, sql

Surgiu uma dúvida ao montar uma instrução sql. Tenho vários registros em uma tabela chamada `db_contrato`, queria acrescentar o numero 0 na frente de todos os registros, por enquanto defini o coluna contrato como varchar (50) .

db_contrato

```
id|contrato  
1 |3094  --> 03094   
2 |4058  --> 04058   
3 |2020  --> 02020  
4 |1620  --> 01620
```

Comment: Qual banco está usando?

Comment: uso o banco mysql

Comment: se o número for `99`, ele vira `099` ou `00099`?

Comment: se for 99 vira 099

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a função [`concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) para adicionar o zero a esquerda.

```
SELECT concat(0, contrato) FROM tabela
```

[Exemplo - sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b68bc/1)

**Relacionada:**

[Usar CONCAT para ajustar a quantidade de números php mysql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126603/91)

Comment: como aplico update nesses registros pra ficar com o zero na frente?

Comment: @SmokeRohden algo como `update tabela set campo = concat(0, campo) where id = ?`

Comment: obrigado, resolvido!

Answer (score 7):

Se quer número fixo de casas:

```
SELECT LPAD( campo, 6, '0') AS comzeros;
```

Se quer um zero só:

```
SELECT CONCAT( '0', campo) AS umzero;
```

Se tiver o problema de espaços antes, pode fazer um CAST:

```
SELECT LPAD( CAST(campo AS UNSIGNED) ....
```